# How to Query Google Cloud Datastore for array

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have wriiten the query to get the all the list of Event Data entities. The result is Coming like this from the google Data Store.

```
[{
  "key": {
    "id": 5678669024460800,
    "kind": "Event",
    "path": [
      "Event",
      5678669024460800
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "createdAt": "2017-03-27T06:28:58.000Z",
    "users":["test1@xxx.com","test2@xxx.com","test3@xxx.com"]
  }
},
{
  "key": {
    "id": 5678669024460800,
    "kind": "Event",
    "path": [
      "Event",
      5678669024460800
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "createdAt": "2017-03-27T06:28:58.000Z",
    "users":["test1@xxx.com"]
  }
},
{
  "key": {
    "id": 5678669024460800,
    "kind": "Event",
    "path": [
      "Event",
      5678669024460800
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "createdAt": "2017-03-27T06:28:58.000Z",
    "users":["test2@xxx.com","test3@xxx.com"]
  }
}]
```

but i need to Write a Query to filter by Email'id. means i need to fetch the entities which are match with the Email id. For Eg if i pass the emailid as **"test1@xxx.com"** i should get final Result like this. Can anybody help me on this.

```
[{
  "key": {
    "id": 5678669024460800,
    "kind": "Event",
    "path": [
      "Event",
      5678669024460800
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "createdAt": "2017-03-27T06:28:58.000Z",
    "users":["test1@xxx.com","test2@xxx.com","test3@xxx.com"]
  }
},
{
  "key": {
    "id": 5678669024460800,
    "kind": "Event",
    "path": [
      "Event",
      5678669024460800
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "createdAt": "2017-03-27T06:28:58.000Z",
    "users":["test1@xxx.com"]
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

The GQL query would be something like -

```
SELECT * FROM Event WHERE users='test1@xxx.com'
```

You need to make sure the `users` property is indexed in order for the search to work, otherwise you may not get any results back.