# google-cloud-python Is it possible for querying on a list property of an Entity?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking at the documentation (https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/queries.html) and it's not clear to me if it's possible to run a query that returns all members of an entity where a value exists in a ListProperty of those entities.

Example: if I have an Entity called `Books` with a field called `tags` that is a list of strings, is it possible for me to query for all `Books` with `"fiction"` in the `Books.tags` ListProperty?

Comment: Can you please clarify do you have other entities with 'tags' properties, e.g Movies? Does property 'tags' has Array type? Can you please share a screenshot how it looks in Cloud Console?

Answer (score 0):

For python you can do it like this:

```
query = client.query(kind='KindName')
query.add_filter('tags', '=', 'fiction')
```

That returns you all entities which have 'fiction' in tag StringList property.

More information and insights you can get [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#array_values).

UPD:

If you need to query only Books field you need to deploy [composite indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#composite_indexes).

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as [How to Query Google Cloud Datastore for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191718/how-to-query-google-cloud-datastore-for-array/43192531) .  You simply need an equality filter on tags.  E.g. `tags = "Fiction"`.

Comment: If he needs to filter only Books, he needs to deploy composite indexes and he is asking about how to do that in python no GQL.